# Change php file after execution

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created php script which gets data and writes it to XML file. the task is executed by using for loop in php. for today execution it will run from 1 to 10.
but when I will execute the script again I want it to continue from 11 to 20 in for loop. but as I have written for 1 to 10 in php file it will execute every time same.
These values fetch the proper value from the server is their any way to update for value every time script execute.
Sample Code:

```
    for ($i=1; $i<2; $i++)
{
    //$url = $link3;
    $url = $link1 . $i . $link2;
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $file=curl_exec($ch);


    $fileName = "data.xml";
if ( file_exists($fileName))    {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($fileName);
}
else    {
    $xml= new SimpleXMLElement('<results />');
}
$array = json_decode ($file, true);
// Remove _class element
foreach ( $array['results'] as $key=>$result )   {
    unset($array['results'][$key]['_class']);
}
arrayToXml($array['results'], $xml);
$xml->asXML($fileName);

}
```

Based on the Value of i API URL is decided and I also refer page from API I can fetch max 10 page at a time. So i have to execute this script after few days .

Comment: Don't try to change the file, just try to think of a pointer to the last record done.. Maybe another sql table? Local file, anything for the script to read..  XY Problem ?

Comment: have you tried `for ($i=$start; $i < $start + 10; $i++) {actions}` ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I agree, but given the **question** if the script is finished executing, the `$start` reference is lost.

Comment: it's not a big problem - he can save last val into database

Comment: If your adding to an XML file, can you show how this file is built?

Comment: If you can share an example of your code and what it does, it would be easier to help you find a way.

Comment: Code added.. it is Json to xml convertor with filter.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Put this at the beginning of your code:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['start']) {
   $start = $_SESSION['start'] = 1;
}
else {
   $start = $_SESSION['start'] += 10;
}
session_write_close();
```

The first time you run the code `$_SESSION['start']` will not be set and so `$start` will be 1. On subsequent runs `$start` will come from `$_SESSION['start']` and will increment by 10 each time.